# ASP.NET Response.Write On Two Different Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Hi would like to know how can i display the response write of a certain page on a page from a different server.

ex.

```
    Server1.HelloWorld.aspx has Response.Write("HELLO WORLD");

    Server2.Default.aspx gets the response from Page1.aspx 
and display it without using server sided code..
```

is this possible, because i know this is possible for images.

Thank you in advance for your help!

UPDATE: I would just need a text response from a page... something like "DONE" "PENDING"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to do a `GET` request for the relevant page you need to download a response from, here's a basic example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://server/HelloWorld.aspx"
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Have a look at [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for more options such as error handling etc.

Comment: We'll so there's no way i can do it without server side code? Because im trying to avoid doing any sever sided code for the receiver of the response since its on a different project.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much content there is and what kind of content, I'd say just use AJAX or an iframe. That way you don't need any server-side code.

Comment: i am trying to avoid the iframe because its just a simple text response a single word to be exact. like "HELLO"